# How to Launch Built In Apps for Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

So I am coming from Windows Phone Silverlight into the new Windows Phone runtime apps and Universal apps. I am attempting to build my first app after doing several of the tutorials from channel9. My question is, and maybe I am not googling this correctly, but how might I launch the built in apps in Windows 8 similar to Windows Phone 8 runtime? I've already built a sample using the runtime following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn741261.aspx but what are the Uri Schemes for built in apps in Windows 8?